# Vue-Cli-Service - Skipping webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs

How can you make the **vue cli service** compile code while skipping webpack? I just need it to use babel.

Basically im trying to avoid code like this:

```
/******/(function (modules) {
  // webpackBootstrap
  /******/ // The module cache
  /******/var installedModules = {};
  /******/
  /******/ // The require function
  /******/function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
    /******/
    /******/ // Check if module is in cache
    /******/if (installedModules[moduleId]) {
      /******/return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
      /******/
    }
    /******/ // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    /******/var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
      /******/i: moduleId,
      /******/l: false,
      /******/exports: {}
      /******/ };
    /******/
    /******/ // Execute the module function
    /******/modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
    /******/
    /******/ // Flag the module as loaded
    /******/module.l = true;
    /******/
    /******/ // Return the exports of the module
    /******/return module.exports;
```

Obviously this is just a part but I think you get the idea. So is a clean build possible? The type of output im looking for is:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = main;
function main(_ref) {
  var x = _ref.x,
      y = _ref.y,
      contextPath = _ref.contextPath,
      configuration = _ref.configuration;

  var node = document.getElementById(y);

  node.innerHTML = "test";
}
```

Where the source file is:

```
export default function main({x, contextPath, y, configuration}) {
    
    const node = document.getElementById(y);

    node.innerHTML ="test";
    
}
```

Transpiled with the following command:

```
babel --source-maps -d build src
```

However, im trying to get the same to work with the vue-cli-service but it destroys my code with all the namespacing and dependency requires:

```
vue-cli-service build --dest build src/index.js
```

This is my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    filenameHashing: false,
    chainWebpack: config => config.optimization.minimize(false),
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            filename: "./index.js"
        }
    },
    css: {
      extract: {
        filename: "./index.css"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need vue-cli then, when babel is good enough for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the webpack bootstrap code to another file by setting [optimization.runtimeChunk](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) option

```
...
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: true
}
...
```

That is the closest thing I can think of that suites your needs.